# '[]' appended to the end of my post request parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make post request with the following parameters:

`const postParams = { 'submission': submission };`

However, when the request is actually sent, I observe that `submission` becomes `submission[]` in the browser's network tab. This is problematic because my server expects `submission` and not `submission[]`. Check the image below for more information.

[Note that the [] was appended to `submission`][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXpNq.png

Note that submission (the variable) is an array of integers, so while it makes sense why the [] is attached, is there a way to get rid of that?

Below is the full function.

```
    const postParams = {  submission: str_sub };
    console.log(postParams)
    $.post(root+'/problems/multiple_choice/'+problem_pk+'/run',
            postParams,
            function(data) {
               // Omitted / not relevant
            })
     .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus); });
```

Comment: what is the output of console.log(postParams) ?

Comment: Hi Suresh, thanks for responding. Here's the output: 
`
{
  "submission": [
    "4"
  ]
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is jQuery's default behaviour where it follows PHP (instead of traditional) conventions.

See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Use `.ajax` instead of `.post` and include `traditional: true` in the options object.

```
$.ajax(
    root+'/problems/multiple_choice/'+problem_pk+'/run',
    {
        data: postParams,
        traditional: true,
        success: (data) => { ... }
    }(
```

Comment: Thank you Quentin, that worked. Had to add a method: 'POST' in there but other than that it solved my issue. Marking as correct.